Blazor 8 sample: multiple DB reloads
I'm using the MS sample (https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples) as it's about all I need to re-write reports for a legacy DB. I notice it seems to reload from the DB without interaction from me i.e. just opening the home page. It seems like it's going into home.razor a number of times (e.g. it hits my breakpoint on _lastPage initialization) causing it to query the DB each time. With the simple/local DB they use that's not much of a performance issue but with a real/remote DB it adds a lot of time.
So what's triggering the 'refresh' and can/should I avoid it?

Please put the address of page or component you have problem with  instead of putting address of whole project

You don't say which example you're using, but I'm guessing you're talk about the double loading of pages when the SPA starts.  If so see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/78723214/13065781

Blazor Web app - with contacts DB

Blazor Web app - with contacts DB https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples/tree/main/8.0/BlazorSample_BlazorWebApp

user can refresh and get data again as much as they want there is two ways to limit this
1- use rate limit to avoid multiple requests from single IP or user at a second how to use rate limit in asp.net
2- use the response cache to make sure you are not getting a single data from the database multiple times how to use response cache in asp.net
3- use API gateway to do rate limiting and response cache and load balancing (it's not necessary but it's good)
at this project there is multiple homes.Razor at this GitHub project , in some of them I saw they use Navigation.NavigateTo inside OnAfterRender , so when your page is rendered fully it's redirect you to another page or the current page with a different URL parameter.
 protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        // Ensure we're on the same (correct) page.
        if (_lastPage < 1)
        {
            Navigation.NavigateTo("/1");
            return;
        }

        // Normalize the page values.
        if (Filters.PageHelper.PageCount > 0)
        {
            if (Page < 1)
            {
                Navigation.NavigateTo("/1");
                return;
            }
            if (Page > Filters.PageHelper.PageCount)
            {
                Navigation.NavigateTo($"/{Filters.PageHelper.PageCount}");
                return;
            }
        }
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }


Thanks Regestea. As I mentioned about all the reloads happen during the initial page view with no interaction from me.
